# Nanoc layout compile Rules

Tags: ruby, rules, nanoc

I'm working with nanoc and I want my index.html to point to specific layout so I created that layout and it is called nosidebar.html

My Rules looks like:

```
compile 'index.html' do 
  layout 'nosidebar'
end
```

and this doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done exactly what you are but maybe something like this:

```
compile '/' do 
  rep.layout 'nosidebar'
end
```

Answer (score 11):

You can always add something like:

```
compile '*' do
  if item.binary?
    # don’t filter binary items
  else
    layout item[:layout] || 'default'
  end
end
```

That means you can just decide the template on the file by adding:

```
---
layout: nosidebar
---
```

at the yaml front matter of the file.