# How to specify layout in nanoc?

Tags: nanoc

In Jekyll, we write layout structure in a HTML file and put it in `_layout` folder. Say, the `_layout` folder has file named `welcome.html`, for a webpage to use it, we simply specify as follows:

```
---
title: Awesome webpage
layout: welcome
---
```

How to do the same when using nanoc? I thought it works the same way, but unfortunately, it seems like not picking up the welcome template. It is just picking up the default.html template.

Is it because of the file called `rule` which has the following lines?

```
compile '/' do
  filter :erb
  layout 'default'
end
```

I want only one specific file to pick up the `welcome` layout. How to do it?

Comment: Related: [Nanoc layout compile Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5254834/1591669) ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9881713/1591669) might be a solution for you)

Comment: Thanks @unor That worked like a charm. I didn't know how to tweak the rules thingy until now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nanoc layout compile Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254834/nanoc-layout-compile-rules)

Answer (score 3):

In the *Rules* file, call `#layout` like this:

```
compile '/' do
  filter :erb
  layout @item[:layout]
end
```

This will call `#layout` with whatever is in the `layout` attribute of the item.

To fall back to a default when no `layout` attribute is specified, use `#fetch`:

```
compile '/' do
  filter :erb
  layout @item.fetch(:layout, '/default.*')
end
```

This will use whatever layout is specified in the `layout` attribute, falling back to the layout that matches `/default.*`.

For your specific case, you probably want the `layout` attribute to be something like `/welcome.html`, like this:

```
---
title: Awesome webpage
layout: /welcome.html
---
```

... but you can also manipulate the string you get back from `#fetch` if you prefer, so that putting just `welcome` in the item metadata will work. This would be less work overall if you were importing a *lot* of Jekyll pages, for example.

Comment: ```/welcome.*``` to be added in the webpage which needs the welcome.html template?

Comment: I clarified the answer a little, hope that helps.